# Unable to detach a USB device on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, usb, unmounting

I was using `udisks` to *unmount* and *detach* USB devices with following commands which work just fine on Ubuntu 10.04:

```
udisks --unmount /dev/sdb1
udisks --detach /dev/sdb
```

Because `udisks` is not available in Ubuntu 14.04, I was trying to use `udisksctl`. It works for `unmount`:

```
udisksctl unmount --block-device /dev/sdb1
```

But when I use `udiskctl` or `umount` to **detach** the device as:

```
udiskctl power-off -p /dev/sdb
```

or

```
umount -p /dev/sdb
```

it gives following error:

```
(udisksctl unmount:17787): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_object_manager_get_object: assertion 'g_variant_is_object_path (object_path)' failed
```

How can I detach device in Ubuntu 14.04 with other existing commands if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be that you are telling the path to the device instead of the path to the block device.

Try the next command:

```
udiskctl power-off -b /dev/sdb
```

With `-b` you are specifying the path to the device.

Source:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/342188/how-to-auto-mount-from-command-line

Comment: Thanks `udiskctl power-off -b /dev/sdb` worked!